# Is it possible to automatically move other strips while dragging another strip?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Imagine you click a drag a strip on the sequencer. When the strip comes in contact with another strip I think it would be useful if the stationary strip would adjust around the influence of the strip I'm dragging. Perhaps swapping places, for instance.

Another automatic adjustment I wonder about is when adjusting after making a knife cut and grabbing one of cross sections. Then when I drag that handle, if I move it as if to overlap the intersection, then the other strip would adjust it's length to compensate as you move it.

It seems at some point I saw an option for it, but I can't remember the name for it. The word "scrobble" comes to mind, but I've found nothing about it. I have a strange memory. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request and not an actual question. These should be reported to Blender's tracker instead.

Comment: @Polosson  I don't see it as a feature request.  He's asking if it is possible, not requesting that the feature be added.

Comment: Nowadays you can slide your strips if that helps...

Comment: @Samoth Similar to my description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's possible. You can use the "Expand to fit" option which is enabled by hitting <kbd>G</kbd> for grab and then you can hit <kbd>G</kbd> again to toggle "Expand to fit" permanently or hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> to use toggle it temporarily.

When you have three strips with the new one selected but not yet in your final row:

[image: Three strips]

Just hit <kbd>G</kbd> to grab and then <kbd>G</kbd> again and place it "over" the existing strips:

[image: Grab with "Expand to fit ON"]

Confirm with left mouse button (<kbd>LMB</kbd>) or <kbd>Enter</kbd> and there you have the strip inserted in between the two existing ones:

[image: Result]

And to answer your second question: Just snap the handle next to the other strips one with dragging it and holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Then just <kbd>Shift</kbd>-select the other handle and slide both of them with <kbd>G</kbd>.

Moving a single handle works with expand to fit as well (even though, the next strip is then moved and not trimmed in length).

Finally you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to swap two adjacent strips.

Comment: This works well enough. Thank you for your time and effort that was put into this well thought out post.